# How to change ip address into a name customized

Tags: apache-http-server, virtualization, ip, localhost, virtual-host

I can access my local WAMP with 192.168.1. However, I wish to make it prettier.

Can I somehow make Apache recognize 192.168.1 as text similiar to a website (i.e. mysite.com or just mysite)? How can I adjust it in Apache? 
I tried way to do.in host file, but I found that the browser always bring me to the search once I type my ip s new.name.

I heard about using virtual host but have no idea how to setup correctly. Help will be really appreciated!
Thank You

Comment: you can do this with a host file edit on the CLIENT, but not on the server. names translate to IP addresses on the client side; otherwise the client doesn't know how to get to the server at all.

Comment: [apache virtual hosts](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts/examples.html) and the [google search](https://www.google.com/search?hl=en&source=hp&q=apache+virtual+host&gbv=2&oq=apache+virtual+host&gs_l=heirloom-hp.3..0l10.472.2734.0.2934.19.12.0.5.5.0.220.1065.0j4j2.6.0....0...1ac.1.34.heirloom-hp..8.11.1135.PW3wpHqGrZg)

Answer (score 3):

To do this, you can either change the HOSTS file on each PC or you need a local DNS service running inside your local network.

If you only have a couple of PC's to deal with, changing the HOSTS file is easy. It is located at:

```
C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc
```

You can simply add an entry like this:

```
192.168.1.x    mywamp.local  # or just mywamp, the dotty bit is optional, it is just a name
```

Running up a local DNS is slightly more challenging and worthy of a separate question.